# libarchive error code -30 opening a tarball: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: npm, tar, libarchive

I have a file resolving service that needs to extract and read .tgz files.  I'm using libarchive to do this.  This is working for almost all of the tarballs I have, but with one of them, I get

```
 error code: -30 Unrecognized archive format.
```

I have enabled all filters and formats:

```
  archive_read_support_filter_all(archive.get());
  archive_read_support_format_all(archive.get());
  int archive_open_error = archive_read_open_filename(
      archive.get(), std::string(archive_file_path).c_str(),
      /*block_size=*/1024);
```

If I run `file` on it, I get

```
gzip compressed data, original size modulo 2^32 48102400
```

if I run `tar -xf` on it, it extracts fine.

Any advice on how to proceed here?  I could extract and rebuild the tarball presumably, but I'd love to get libarchive to handle this correctly so it'd be future proof for similar tarballs I get in the future (they come from `npm` fwiw).

Thanks!